# pattern matching for loop repeating more than desired

Tags: c++, string, for-loop, substring

I've never used string or string functions until today and I'm running into a problem that I don't understand. This program as is, should just accept a command line argument, load the file and display it to memory. However it displays it multiple times. I'm pretty sure the for loop is the problem, but it is the same technique as what is used in the programming reference I am using.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

char* getFile( char* fileName ){
    std::fstream inFile( fileName );
    if( !inFile ) std::cout << "Could not open " << fileName << ".\n";
    else{
        inFile.seekg(0,inFile.end);
        int len = inFile.tellg();
        inFile.seekg(0,inFile.beg);
        char* buffer = new char[len];
        inFile.read( buffer, len);
        inFile.close();
        std::cout.write(buffer,len);
        return buffer;
        }

    }
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 2) std::cout << "Parameter required\n";
    else{
        std::string f = getFile( argv[1] );
        for( size_t i = f.find( 0x0A, 0 ); i != std::string::npos ; i = f.find( 0x0A, i) ){
            std::cout << f.substr(0,i)<<std::endl;
            i++;
            }
    }
}
```

I see at least one of the problems with my code. I re-wrote the loop as a while loop because it was easier to follow and paid a little more attention to where I am starting and stopping. However it still seems to be printing twice.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    if(argc != 2) std::cout << "Parameter required\n";
    else{
        std::string f = getFile( argv[1] );
        size_t start = 0;
        size_t end = 1;
        while( end != std::string::npos ){
            end = f.find( 0x0A, start );
            std::cout << f.substr(start,end)<<std::endl;
            start = ( end + 1 );
            }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the i++ accomplish this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Split the string f based on location of the newline character? And print each part on a new line?

Comment: Yes. The code works as is except it prints the file many times. Not a continuous loop but quite a few times.

Comment: For one, the algorithm is now written so that for each match it prints a substring starting from the beginning up to the match. So, it would print first line, then first and second line, then first, second and third, etc. Keep track of where you start searching. Update that each iteration. Try to step through the code in a debugger to see what is exactly happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you have two printing statements that are displaying the contents of the file.

The first print statement is this one:

```
std::cout.write(buffer,len);
```

The second one is this:

```
std::cout << f.substr(0,i)<<std::endl;
```